# Reading a file using FileInputStream

Tags: java, fileinputstream, fileoutputstream

Firstly, I use FileOutputStream to write an big integer into the file.

e.g.

```
int a = 2051741;
fileA.write(a);
```

Then later, when I use FileInputStream to read the data.

e.g.

```
int b = fileA.read();
```

When I printout `b`, it would be something small like 112

Why does that happen? How can I readout the original integer?

Comment: You are writing a byte not an int.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html#write-int-, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read--

Answer (score 2):

[public void write(int b)
           throws IOException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#write(int))

> Writes the specified byte to this file output stream. Implements the write method of OutputStream.

You need to decorate your OutputStream with another type of OutputStream that supports it. i.e. DataOutputStream

```
    DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("MyFile.txt"));
    out.writeInt(20);
    out.writeInt(53432542);
    out.writeLong(5234843258938L);
    out.close();

    DataInputStream in  = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream("MyFile.txt"));
    System.out.println(in.readInt());
    System.out.println(in.readInt());
    System.out.println(in.readLong());
    in.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

[`FileInputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html) and [`FileOutputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html) handles bytes of data. More specifically, [`read()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html#read--) reads a single byte and [`write(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#write-int-) writes a byte.

The Javadoc of [`OutputStream.write(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html#write-int-) says:

> Writes the specified byte to this output stream. The general contract for write is that one byte is written to the output stream. The byte to be written is the eight low-order bits of the argument b. The 24 high-order bits of b are ignored.

This means that when you are giving an `int` value, the 24 high-order bits of bit are ignored. Taking your argument of `2051741`, dropping the 24 high-order bits, you come down to `2051741 & 0xFF = 157`.

Which is what you end up reading: a small number like `157`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `Scanner` for reading your file's contents:

```
 Scanner s = new Scanner(file)
 int b = s.nextInt();
 System.out.print(b);
```

This is for reading a single value from a file,here's an approach for times when your file has more than one value:

```
 while(s.hasNext()){
       int b[i] = s.nextInt();
       i++;
       }
     for(int x:b)
     System.out.print(b);
```

You may also use methods like `nextBigInteger()` for big `integer` values.